# Repeating numbered capture groups in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Imagine I'm trying to parse the following html using Perl regex:

```
<h4>test</h4> <p>num1</p> <p>num2</p> <p>num3</p>
<h4>test</h4> <p>num1</p> <p>num2</p> <p>num3</p> <p>num4</p>
```

using the following regular expression:

```
<h4>([\w\s]*)</h4>(?:<p>([\w\s]+)</p>)+
```

How would the numbered groups be structured in Perl? $1 would obviously contain the `<h4>` tag text, but when the capture groups repeat, are the captured `<p>` tags then sent to $2 $3 and $4? Is there a good way to capture all the `<p>` tags in an array? Is this even something perl supports? Or am I forced to write a single regex for `<h4>`, then another for the `<p>`'s?

(I'm aware I could use `HTML::Tree` or something similar to parse the html, but this is just a simplified example I'm using to help describe the question, I'm really only interested in how repeated numbered capture groups work in Perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you repeat a capturing group, only the last matching group will be stored in the matcher.

If you want to get each match from a repeating group, you could use a replaceAll with a callback function or iterate through the matches one by one.

Most languages also have a "match all", which I don't know how to do in perl. This usually stores all matches into an array for you, but repeating groups are still stored only as last matched group.

Comment: i figured this might be the case, i'll just write and next a second regex to handle the p tags. thanks.